# Date validations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, date-comparison

I have two text fields. In these text fields, I am getting dates from a picker in this format: "mm-dd-yyyy". What I want to do is validate the dates from one text field to the other, so that both text fields are not filled with the same date and also the first text field's date is always greater than the second's. Can anyone explain how to do this on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[NSDate compare:];`[From documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-compare_)

> `compare`:
>
> Returns an `NSComparisonResult` value
>   that indicates the temporal ordering
>   of the receiver and another given
>   date.
>
> `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> anotherDate
>
> The date with which to compare the receiver.
>   This value must not be nil. If the value is nil, the behavior is
>   undefined and may change in future
>   versions of Mac OS X.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> If:
>
> The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame
>
> The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
>
> The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.

Answer (score 0):

Since, from textFields, you will be getting strings, you can do stringComparison.

> [textField1.text
>   isEqualToString:textField2.text];

Comment: would it help to know which date is greater?